# Jquery UI Range Slider - Convert number to currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently using a range slider for price ranges of £0 to £2,000,000. Currently, everything is working correctly apart from the prices not being formatted as currency (i.e the£500,000 value is currently being shown as £500000 - without the commas). Here's the code:

jQuery

```
  /* SALES SLIDER */ 
  $( "#slider-range-price-sales" ).slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 2000000,
  step: 50000,
  values: [ 0, 2000000],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $("#minPrice").val("£" + ui.values[0]).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "£1");
      $("#maxPrice").val("£" + ui.values[1]);
  }
});

$("#minPrice").val("£" + $("#slider-range-price-sales").slider("values", 0));
$("#maxPrice").val("£" + $("#slider-range-price-sales").slider("values", 1));
```

HTML

```
<div id="slider-range-price-sales"></div>

<div class="priceContainer">

   <div class="left"><input type="text" id="minPrice" name="minPrice" style="border: 0; color: #3D80E9; background:#F2F2F2; font-weight: bold;" /></div>
   <div class="right"><input type="text" id="maxPrice" name="maxPrice" style="border: 0; color: #3D80E9; background:#F2F2F2; font-weight: bold;" /></div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/RwfFH/

I've tried reformatting the minimum price with JavaScript .replace to no avail.. any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
jamie

Comment: @isherwood - why did you include a fiddle with bootstrap?

Comment: Oops. My mistake. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/RwfFH/

Comment: This may be helpful. The fact that you're using a slider isn't really relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function which add comma like you want

```
function addCommas(nStr){
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

and the jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RwfFH/1/.

Comment: this little function seems to have done the trick. Thanks a lot! I appreciate it :)

Comment: @DonovanCharpin if the format is something like this - `1,00,00,000`. Then?

Comment: Try to use `/(\d+)(\d{2})/` instead of `/(\d+)(\d{3})/` in the rgx variable.

Answer (score 4):

To keep in line with what you are doing you just need to make a couple changes. I'll point out that you need to have modified the value before you set it in the .val() operation. Also, replace returns a new string it does not modify the original. That being done, you just needed a little tweak in the regex, $1, will use the matched value in the replace.

```
$("#minPrice").val("£" + ui.values[0].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
```